# Running C++ binaries without the runtime redistributable (Server2k3, XPSP3)

Tags: c++, windows, windows-xp, runtime

Having written a CGI application in Visual Studio 2008 and debigged it locally, I uploaded it to a Windows Server 2003 OS where it promptly failed to run.

I am guessing I need to install the wretched Runtime distributable, but after reading this:

http://kobyk.wordpress.com/2007/07/20/dynamically-linking-with-msvcrtdll-using-visual-c-2005/

I am wondering if it makes more sense to ignore this side by side stuff and just re-write the app.

I am guessing Windows Server 2003 does not have MSCRVT version I need?
Does Windows Server 2003 have it?

When it comes to deploying thick clients, I would like to distribute the required dlls with my app. 
What are they assuming I just INCLUDE iostream, sstream, string?

Does it change significantly if I add windows.h?

Added:

Using the /MT switch recommended below

C / C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library -> Multi-threaded(/MT)

(You will probably need to do a clean:

Build -> Clean

in order to avoid the error message

"Failed to save the updated manifest to the file")

bloated my app from 38k to 573k. Thats what I call Significant (imagine if that were your salary). Since many instances of this app will be loaded and unloaded constantly (requiring precious memory and processor resources) I would like to find a better (smaller) solution.

I understand this is not important for many situations today and not the focus of many developers, hence the trend to .NOT and 60MB runtimes, but this is what I want to do.

Added:

After removing the debugging to get the project to compile:

Project -> Propeties -> c/c++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions (remove DEBUG;)

the size was reduced to 300k, and it will run.

Added:
As suggested by Chris Becke below, copying:
msvcm90.dll
msvcp90.dll
msvcr90.dll
Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest
To the directory of the application will provide all the runtime needed.

Using Visual Studio 6 has been suggested a few times, but it does not support Vista (or Windows 7 we assume) Other solutions that do not require a runtime distributable would probably me MASM or even a flavor of Basic. Unfortunately that defeats the purpose of using a high level OOP language like C++.

So long as I do need to require the C++ redistributable be installed, the trade off is an additional 260k. Thats acceptable

Comment: Does *what* change significantly?  Pretty much, nearly anything you build with VS2008 is going to require the runtime install as well.

Comment: You're going to need the runtime almost no matter what. Your choice is in *how* you include it. The most convenient method is to use the statically linked version. Then you don't have to distribute a separate dll at all. Failing that, you have half a million ways to distribute the dll. Ranging from the super-complicated side-by-side thing that requires reading 15 pages of documentation, to just putting it in a folder with the correct name in your app's root folder, which is pretty manageable.

Comment: I'm not sure how effective this would be, but try fiddling around with the compiler/linker options. There were a few that affected the executable size (something about optimizing for size and removing unused stuff).

Comment: Adding /MT causes the C and C++ runtimes to be statically linked instead of dynamically linked, hence the increase in size. Not sure if this actually makes a difference, because in both cases the runtime still needs to be loaded into your processes address space. 

Why doesn't it run now? What error message do you get? Try loading it with depends.exe and see what Dlls it is looking for.

Comment: See above. Its looking for some version of MSVCRT that needs to be installed side by side (thats what the C++ runtime does). I CANNOT do that in this case.

Comment: I'm confused, with /MT it's still asking for MSVCRT? Or you just don't want to use /MT? If you can't install MSVCRT, you'll need to use an older version of VS, like 2005. Then you can just put the runtime Dlls in the current folder. Or you can install the Dlls, Microsoft provides a redistributable installer.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=A5C84275-3B97-4AB7-A40D-3802B2AF5FC2&displaylang=en

Comment: Seriously? You think 500kb memory usage is "a significant problem"? Really? What computer are you running this on, a pocket calculator?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A fuller list of options:

- Rewrite the app so that theres no C/C++ usage at all.
- Switch to Visual Studio 6 or a mingw based toolset like Code::Blocks - these use the already distributed msvcrt.dll as their runtime.
- Build using the /MT switch. This builds the necessary runtime functions into your exe. Which will bloat it. But that bloat (frankly) is less overhead than loading separate dll's.
- Distribute the VS9 runtime as a 'private sxs' install. This entails copying the contents of `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC90.CRT` into the same folder as your application's exe. If you have applied SP1, then this folder will contain the SP1 runtime, but your application will be asking for the RTM runtime (go figure). Add `_BIND_TO_CURRENT_CRT_VERSION` to your projects defines, rebuild and that should sort itself out.
- There is apparently a vc_redist.exe that can be obtained for VS9. Find that or figure out the MSI or installer mojo required to actually install the above assembly (being the contents of Microsoft.VC90.CRT) into the shared sxs store.

Answer (score 13):

Let me revise my answer:

You have a few options:

1) Install the VC++2008 runtime. You can [download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?familyid=9B2DA534-3E03-4391-8A4D-074B9F2BC1BF&displaylang=en) and installer for them. Merge modules for them are also available.

2) Link against the runtime statically (/MT or C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library: Multi-threaded). This will increase the size of your executable, but it won't depend on any Dlls. If you are worried about size, only use the C standard library or only use the Windows API directly.

3) Use an older version of VC++. 2005 and earlier did not require the runtime to be installed. The Dlls could be placed in the same directory as the executable. If you use VC++6.0 the runtimes will be installed on all versions of windows, otherwise you need to install it yourself.

Comment: I think you mean

Project Properties -> C / C++ -> Cod Generation -> RUntime Library -> Multi-threaded(/MT)

Comment: Coder or Cod? Haha.. you are probably right, i tried to do it from memory.

Comment: Project Properties -> C / C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library -> DROPDOWN -> Multi-threaded (/MT)