# I don't see the "Publish" button. How to make standalone exe-file from C++ code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, exe, publish

Problem is the same as here:

1. [Visual Studio 2017 - Not Able to see Publish - Missing Profile / Deployment Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42975559/visual-studio-2017-not-able-to-see-publish-missing-profile-deployment-opti)
2. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/129404/missing-publish-menu-in-netcore-web-project-right.html

except the fact that I didn't see the button earlier (I've started coding in Visual Studio just recently). I've installed some packages, which were adviced in mentioned topics, like "Azure" and "ASP.NET", but it didn't solve the problem. I don't understand, how it could help (I code on C++ and have not to use these packages, do I?) and what exactly I should do (maybe I've downloaded something wrong).

Thank you in advance!

---

### Update

If I understand right, there is no way to "publish" C++ code, according to:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6998eadb-36fb-4a97-bba5-0de49d533732/how-can-i-publish-a-visual-c-project-?forum=vsclassdesigner

Then, how to make standalone exe-file, that doesn't require something other like .pdb, .ipdb and .iobj and can be run on another coumputer without Visual Studio?

Comment: The command that creates the binary is called "Build"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command that creates the binary is called "Build".

I can't say for sure, but I think that "Debug" builds to run on another computer need vcredist, while "Release" builds can run without anything else. Again, I am not sure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, "Release" (with help of "Build" button) creates several files (see https://ibb.co/nxyyDV) as well as "Debug" (see https://ibb.co/hpLdDV). According to mentioned topics, there should be "Publsih" button in "Build" category in upper menu bar. And, it seems, it should be only for web-applications/ Is there any way to combine those 4 files in the picture?

Comment: The exe can run without the other files. The other files help with debugging and incremental building, they are not needed for running the exe. C++ doesn't have a publish command.

Comment: It's not true, because that exe-file doesn't work without those other files on another computer without Visual Studio. A message appears after exe-file running, and it says about a need for some dll-files

Comment: @Olexot you will get the same thing with the files also. It's not those files that are needed, it's vcredist.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581105/running-c-binaries-without-the-runtime-redistributable-server2k3-xpsp3

Comment: I misunderstood a lot of things. You are right, "Release" builds standalone exe-file. Thank you!